# Making all indices in the subscript the same size

Tags: subscripts

Consider the following code:

`$\widetilde{R}_{\infty(i j) l, \underbrace{\infty\dots\infty}_{k-1}}$`

It appears as:

[image]

Note that the $\infty$ signs after the comma appear larger than the previous indices. I want them all to be the same size. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect that there's some warning... by the way, Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: $...\underbrace{\scriptstyle\infty\dots\infty}..."?

Comment: @user202729- It does. Thanks!